# Double insertion of data using modal

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I`m working on PHP + MYSQL + AJAX project. I used Bootstrap Modal when adding data. After first time I click add, it will insert two records however it only occurs in its first time click.

Is there any way to prevent saving two records.

I appreciate your help and suggestion. Thanks

This is my modal

```
<div id="userModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <form method="post" id="user_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add User</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sName" maxlength="150" id="sName" placeholder="Enter your Name" />  
                        <span id='remainingC'></span>                
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Username</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sUsername" maxlength="20" id="sUsername" placeholder="Enter your Username"/>   
                        <span id='remainingCu'></span>                
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Birthday</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sBirthday" 
                        onchange ="getAge();" maxlength="20" id="sBirthday" placeholder="YYYY-mm-dd"/>                                       
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Age</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="iAge" maxlength="3" id="iAge" placeholder="Autofill when you fill Birthday"/>                                          
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sEmail" id="sEmail" placeholder="Enter your Email - eg. jb@gmail.com"/>                                        
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My AJAX requests

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#add_button').click(function(){
    $('#user_form')[0].reset();
    $('.modal-title').text("Add User");
    $('#action').val("Add");
    $('#operation').val("Add");
    // $('#user_uploaded_image').html('');
});

var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
    "processing":true,
    "serverSide":true,
    "order":[],
    "ajax":{
        url:"fetch.php",
        type:"POST"
    },
    "columnDefs":[
        {
            "targets":[0, 3, 4],
            "orderable":false,
        },
    ],

});

$(document).on('submit', '#user_form', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var sName = $('#sName').val();
    var sUsername = $('#sUsername').val();
    var sBirthday = $('#sBirthday').val();
    var iAge = $('#iAge').val();
    var sEmail = $('#sEmail').val();

    if(sName != '' && sUsername != '' && sBirthday != '' && iAge != '' && sEmail != '')
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"insert.php",
            method:'POST',
            data:new FormData(this),
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                $('#user_form')[0].reset();
                $('#userModal').modal('hide');
                dataTable.ajax.reload();
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Both Fields are Required");
    }
});
```

This is my Function for adding (insert.php)

```
if($_POST["operation"] == "Add")
{
    $statement = $connection->prepare("
        INSERT INTO users (sName, sUsername, sBirthday, iAge, sEmail) 
        VALUES (:sName, :sUsername, :sBirthday, :iAge, :sEmail)
    ");
    $result = $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':sName'    =>  $_POST["sName"],
            ':sUsername'    =>  $_POST["sUsername"],
            ':sBirthday'    =>  $_POST["sBirthday"],
            ':iAge' =>  $_POST["iAge"],
            ':sEmail'   =>  $_POST["sEmail"]

        )
    );
    if(!empty($result))
    {
        echo 'Data Inserted';
    }
}
```

Duplicate data after 1st click of add button in modal:
[Duplicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgvFW.png)

Comment: Try using `$(this).off("click"); ` in your javascript event

Comment: Can you please elaborate more. Thank you.

Comment: Once more alternative, you can disable submit button after click. You wrote `event.preventDefault();` below that write, `$(this).off("click");` and if possible, check id or class of modal submit and disable that button. Its better to apply unique key constraint on username if it will always be unique in your mysql database. Later you can apply exception handling to catch duplicate entry error.

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked whether duplicate requests occur? If yes, why do they happen - have you tried to set any breakpoints in your JS code to check for that?

Comment: You can disable the `submit` button until your current request is completed. Once your request has returned you can enable the `submit` button. 
You can also validate whether API is creating duplicate data or we are making duplicate request.

Comment: If you don't want to change your js, you can modify  your php function. You can check if the user already exists or not.